# .NET deny anonymous access blocking domain user too

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, iis, .net-framework

We have installed the same .net web app to a few of our servers but one of the server is blocking access for domain users despite only set to deny anonymous access. We used the following web.config to deny anonymous access, just like its supposed to:

```
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
 </authorization>
```

We need to add domain users to the Admin Group on this particular server so they can access the application, while we just want to deny access to anonymous users and allow access for all domain users.

I am not a network/AD guy and just own the application from a developer perspective so I am wondering if there's any IIS/.Net app settings that might cause the issue. We have no other auth related settings in our web.config  and the same config is used for other instances which is authenticating access properly as intended. Is there anything else i should check on my end or recommend the network admin to check?

Our environment:
Windows 2008
IIS 7
.Net 4.5
ASP.Net WebForm Application
One single domain with one DNS server (so far as I know)

Comment: A user would be anonymous until they authenticated even if they were on the domain.  You have not provided enough information to answer your question.  This appears to be a programming problem.

Comment: @Ramhound what other info do you need? And if that's a programming problem why is that the other instances appear to be fine?